# Syntax for django template tag checking object Boolean field

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

Using Django template tags, I am trying to check if an object Boolean field that I passed to the template (using python) is True.

If I print the object on the page I see the value True/False:

```
<p>{{ obj.bool }}</p>
```

I've tried:

```
{% if {{ obj.bool }} == True %}
    HELLO
{% endif %}
```

Which raises a syntax error

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

And:

```
{% if '{{ obj.bool }}' == 'True' %}
    <p>HELLO</p>
{% endif %}
```

Gives me nothing...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need `{{}}` inside tag, just use:

```
{% if obj.bool %}
```